# Google Chrome CSS `filter: blur();` issue – `filter: none;` not respected

Tags: css, google-chrome, filter

[image: Google Chrome CSS Blur Problem]

Correct behaviour: `filter: blur();` should not be applied to the flyout menu (this is shown in Edge, right-hand screenshot).

Google Chrome is ignoring `-webkit-filter: none;` on the flyout menu (left-hand screenshot).

**CSS Code:**

```
#nav { /* Default Navigation Style */
    position: fixed;
    left: -100vw; /* Ensure the Nav is hidden offscreen */
    top: 0;

    width: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100%;

    padding: 5px;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

    font-size: 4vmin;

    overflow: hidden;
    transition: left 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
    z-index: 999;
}

#nav.open {
    left: 0;
    width: 15vw;

    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none; 
}

.nav-open { /* When the Menu is open, blur everything */
    filter: blur(5px);
} /* This gets applied to body and header elements through JavaScript */
```

**Javascript:**

```
var mouseDown = false;

function showMenu() {
    document.querySelector('#nav').className = 'open';
    document.querySelector('body').className = 'nav-open';
    document.querySelector('#header').className = 'nav-open';
    document.querySelector('#nav').focus();
}

function hideMenu() {
    if(mouseDown) { // Prevents the Menu from being hidden when a link is clicked inside it.
            document.querySelector('#nav').focus();
            mouseDown = false;
    }else{ // If no link was clicked, hide the menu
        document.querySelector('#nav').className = '';
        document.querySelector('body').className = ''
        document.querySelector('#header').className = '';
    }
}

document.querySelector('a').onmousedown = function() {
    mouseDown = true; // Detects if a link was clicked
}
```

Any ideas on a possible workaround for Chrome?

Comment: Can you try `!important` on `-webkit-filter: none`?

Comment: At a first glance, I think it might be happening for different reasons: it could be you're applying another filter and overriding the first, or maybe because you're not using the right classes/ids, why don't you add in more of the code?

Comment: Added more code :-)

Comment: Have you tried using `filter: blur(0px)` with your `filter: none`?

Comment: Yes, no difference in behaviour :-(

Comment: A working example (jsfiddle or snippet) will help a lot, my guess is that you have some kind of collision between the elements (or wrong javascript code).

Comment: I've just commented out the line:

    document.querySelector('body').className = 'nav-open';

And the blur is NOT applied to the Menu, however I still want the blur to apply to all other elements.

So lesson learnt:
In Edge, position: fixed, position:absolute removes the element from being a child of the body element, in Chrome, that relationship remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found:

```
document.querySelector('body').className = 'nav-open';
```

Fix:
Replace the above line with one for each of the main DIV elements

```
document.querySelector('#content').className = 'nav-open';
document.querySelector('#slideshow').className = 'nav-open';
document.querySelector('#header').className = 'nav-open';
document.querySelector('#footer').className = 'nav-open';
```

Why? 
It seems that when you use

```
position: fixed || absolute;
```

In Edge, that apparently breaks the Parent->Child relationship in the DOM, so in my first code, applying the blur to the whole of the body did NOT effect the fixed positioned #nav menu. It was no longer a child of the body element.

Google Chrome was doing what it should do.